# how add Slider Slick before top post?

Tags: php, wordpress, slick.js

How do I add slick slider to the front page before the top article and Slick Slider With TAG and 6 post?

```
if ( have_posts() ){
    while ( have_posts() ){
        the_post();

        if( $i == 0 && $paged == 1 ){

            $t_dyn_opt = $dynamic_options;
            $t_dyn_opt['modal'] = '13';
            $t_thumb = 'large';

            $list_out .= '<div class="row">';
                $list_out .= '<div class="col-sm-12">';
                    $list_out .= '<div class="newser-block-grid single-top">';
                        $list_out .= newser_common_block_grid_generate($t_thumb, $t_dyn_opt);
                    $list_out .= '</div>';
                $list_out .= '</div>';
            $list_out .= '</div>';
            $i = 1;

        }else{

            $list_out .= '<div class="row">';
                $list_out .= '<div class="col-sm-12">';
                    $list_out .= '<div class="newser-block-list big-list">';
                        $list_out .= newser_common_block_big_list_generate($thumb_grid, $dynamic_options);
                    $list_out .= '</div>';
                $list_out .= '</div>';
            $list_out .= '</div>';
        }
    }
```

or see the full code here [LINK](https://pastebin.com/1itiNZK6)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to this [slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)? If so, the documentation is pretty thorough. Just include the following in your head tag :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
```

Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Then throw this in at the end of your code (before your closing body tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Once you have that all you have to do is format each slide like so:

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

Finally initialize the slider with this function in a script tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    setting-name: setting-value
  });
});
</script>
```

As for the location I would create a function that creates your slides and then just call that function wherever you need your slider kind of like this

```
function slider($slides) {

    //slides is an array of arrays that contain whatever information you need in each slide

    $slider = "";
    $sliderContent = array();
    $sliderTop = "<div class=\"your-class\">";
    $sliderBottom = "</div>";
    for($i = 0; $i<count($slides); $i++) {
        $sliderContent[] = "<div> use the content from $slides[$i]</div>"; 

    }

    $slider = (!empty($sliderContent))? $sliderTop.implode("",$sliderContent).$sliderBottom: "";
    return $slider; 

}
```

Comment: thanks your answer @Trg3rz, so where do I put the slide function on my website?

Comment: The same place you put your other functions like newser_blog_block_modal_10 or you can add it inline where you are going to use it but be sure to declare it before you use it.

Comment: really I no understand, where is put this 'code' **@Trg3rz**?

Comment: You asked "How do I add slick slider to the **front page before the top article** and Slick Slider With TAG and 6 post?". So I would say open the file that you refer to as **front page** and add the code before the code that calls your articles.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Trig3rz :)